# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near when Creating new Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

Before 4 days ago I was creating a new project normally but yesterday when I'm trying to create a new project I get error `Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near` on ubuntu 18.04.

```
Ionic CLI : 6.5.0
cordova-res : not installed
native-run : not installed
NodeJS : v12.16.2
npm : 6.14.4
OS : Linux 5.3
```

I've tried:

1.) `npm cache clean --force`

2.) `npm uninstall @ionic/cli` + reinstall

3.) removed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) from the system

4.) removed all cache and node and npm files and folders manually

5.) update [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) from v12.16.1 to v12.16.2

I saw the log file and notice my latency is to high but my internet is normal and good and I got the same error nothing fix.

Is there any fix?

Comment: Try to update @angular/cli since most of the files that are being generated in project creation are angular files..

Comment: @MostafaHarb already did update